# Fresh 18.04.1 LTS install, can't login, multiple re-installs.. same result

Tags: server, login

I've re-installed about 5 times, same result each time. username / password combination entered during installation is not recognized. No special chars in pass or username. WTH?? I'd really like to use Ubuntu as my server to setup our intranet web. Why is this an issue??

edit::
username: cshort
password: 4369admin

pretty simple.. and eng/eng keyboard layouts..

Comment: Works for me ;-)

Comment: just try to use a simple password, you would change it after reboot (something like `qwerty123456`, you see what I mean); if it didn't work, then you must have a keyboard failure, or I hope you don't have the same username/password

Answer (score 2):

Could it perhaps be a keyboard layout problem ? perhaps you set the user/password, then configured a slightly different layout that would not be noticeable on the username, but would change the password ?

(This should be a comment if I had the rep, I will delete it if useless or edit otherwise)

Comment: Don't delete it, it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up password-less login, and set up the password after your first login.

Comment: pass is required..